# Determinant of a matrix with $t$ in all off-diagonal entries.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, determinant

It seems from playing around with small values of $n$ that

$$
\det \left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
-1 & t & t & \dots & t\\
t & -1 & t & \dots & t\\
t & t & -1 & \dots & t\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
t  & t & t & \dots& -1
\end{array}\right) = (-1)^{n-1}(t+1)^{n-1}((n-1)t-1)
$$

where $n$ is the size of the matrix.

How would one approach deriving (or at least proving) this formally?

---

**Motivation**

This came up when [someone asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897118/what-is-the-non-trivial-general-solution-of-these-equal-ratios/897300#897300) what is the general solution to:

$$\frac{a}{b+c}=\frac{b}{c+a}=\frac{c}{a+b},$$

and for non-trivial solutions, the matrix above (with $n=3$) must be singular. In this case either $t=-1\implies a+b+c=1$ or $t=\frac{1}{2}\implies a=b=c$.

So I wanted to ensure that these are also the only solutions for the case with more variables.

Comment: Did you try induction?

Comment: Induction combined with [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) should do it.

Comment: Induction is the way to go, but first, subtract the first row from all the other rows to get a much easier calculation.

Comment: When $n=2$ seems to fail. $1-t^2$ RHS, $-2 t^3-3 t^2+1$ LHS, right?

Comment: The matrix size should be $n+1$; @caya gives the $n=2$ case.

Comment: Sorry, the RHS should indeed read $n-1$. There is also a changing sign I think.

Comment: So, there is a typo in the post...

Comment: @caya Yes, apologies. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using elementary operations instead of induction is key.
$$\begin{align}
&\begin{vmatrix}
-1 & t  & t  & \dots & t\\
t  & -1 & t  & \dots & t\\
t  & t  & -1 & \dots & t\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
t  & t & t & \dots& -1
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{vmatrix}
-t-1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & t+1\\
0 & -t-1 & 0 & \dots & t+1\\
0 & 0 & -t-1 & \dots & t+1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
t  & t & t & \dots& -1
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{vmatrix}
-t-1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
0 & -t-1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
0 & 0 & -t-1 & \dots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
t  & t & t & \dots& (n - 1)t -1
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=
(-1)^{n - 1}(t + 1)^{n - 1}((n - 1)t - 1)
\end{align}$$

Comment: For clarity, first he is doing "Row N = Row N - Last Row" then he is doing "Last Row = Last Row - Row N"

Comment: In the second step of the above comment, it makes sense to exchange references to "row" with "column".  For further clarification to the answer, the sign of (n-1)t-1 is always positive (-1^2n); the cofactor expansion along the last row has only one term with a nonvanishing determinant ((n-1)t-1 itself) because the others all yield minors with a zero-column somewhere, and the determinant in the remaining term is simply an (n-1)x(n-1) diagonal with (-t - 1) as each element.  That determinant yields (-t - 1)^(n-1), which here is shown with (-1)^(n-1) factored out of it.

Answer (score 7):

You can write the expression as
$$ \det(t C - (t+1)I)$$
where $C = \mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T$ is the matrix of all $1$'s, formed by the column of ones times its transpose.
Using the identity $\det(I+cr) = 1+rc$, you can first factor out $(t+1)$:
$$ \det(t C - (t+1)I) = (-1)^n(t+1)^n \det\left(I - \frac{t}{t+1} \mathbf{1}\right) = (-1)^n(t+1)^n \left(1 - \frac{nt}{t+1}\right) $$

Comment: That's brilliant, nothing could be more elegant. :)

Comment: +1, but what do you mean by $cr$ and $rc$?  Are these row and column vectors, abbreviated $r$ and $c$, respectively?  (My assumption)

Comment: Correct, they are row and column vectors. I stole that from the Wiki page on Determinant

Answer (score 3):

Note that your matrix is the sum of the matrix $T$ with *all* entries equal to $t$ and the matrix $-(1+t)I$. Therefore the determinant you are asking about is the value at $X=-(1+t)$ of the characteristic polynomial $\chi_{-T}$ of $-T$.

Since $T$ has rank (at most) $1$, its eigenspace for eigenvalue $0$ has dimension $n-1$, so the characteristic polynomial of $-T$ is $\chi_{-T}=X^{n-1}(X+nt)$ (the final factor must be that because the coefficient of $X^{n-1}$ in $\chi_{-T}$ is $\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}-\tr(-T)=nt$). Now setting $X=-(1+t)$ gives 
$$
  \det(-(1+t)I-T)=(-1-t)^{n-1}(-1-t+nt)=(-1-t)^{n-1}(-1+(n-1)t)
$$
as desired.

This kind of question is recurrent on this site; see for instance [Determinant of a specially structured matrix ($a$'s on the diagonal, all other entries equal to $b$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/86644/18880) and [How to calculate the following determinants (all ones, minus $I$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/84206/18880).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another characterization of the result. For convenience, I will take the matrix size as $n+1$ rather than $n$. First, note that we may factor $t$ from each of the $n+1$ rows, and so the determinant may be written as 
$$
\det{[t(M-t^{-1} I_{n+1})]}
=t^{n+1} \det(M-t^{-1} I_{n+1})
$$
 where $(M)_{ij}=1-\delta_{ij}$ for $1\leq i,j\leq n+1$.

Next, observe that $M$ has $n$ independent eigenvectors of the form $\hat{e}_i-\hat{e}_{n+1}$ ($1\leq i\leq n$), each with eigenvalue $-1$; in addition, $M$ also has the eigenvector $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\hat{e}_i$ with eigenvalue $n$. Consequently the characteristic polynomial of $M$ in powers of $t^{-1}$ is $$\det(M-t^{-1} I_{n+1})=(-1-t^{-1})^n (n-t^{-1}) =  t^{-n-1}\cdot (-1)^n (1+t)^n (nt+1)$$ and so the prior result yields the desired identity.