# How to determine the characteristic polynomial of the $4\times4$ real matrix of ones?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

$$\left[\begin{array}{l}1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\end{array}\right]$$

I am having difficulties with calculating this. Currently I'm stuck at finding the determinant of the following matrix:

$$\left[\begin{array}{l}\lambda-1&-1&-1&-1\\-1&\lambda-1&-1&-1\\-1&-1&\lambda-1&-1\\-1&-1&-1&\lambda-1\end{array}\right]$$

Is there a "smart" way/trick to get the result or should I just crunch the numbers through Gaussian elimination? Normally it is not that difficult to do this, but if all the elements of the matrix are the same, it somehow got me confused.

Comment: You first matrix is not a square matrix. For the determinant of a matrix with $a$ on the diagonal, and $b$ elsewhere, there is a formula! Have a look at MSE.

Comment: Here is the popular post @DietrichBurde is referring to:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86644/determinant-of-a-specially-structured-matrix-as-on-the-diagonal-all-other-e.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes, exactly! This post is also recommended at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897469/determinant-of-a-matrix-with-t-in-all-off-diagonal-entries).

Answer (score 2):

Consider any $n \times n$ rank-$1$ matrix $A$ as follows: one of its eigenvalues is its trace and the remaining eigenvalues are zero. Hence, the characteristic polynomial is $$x^{n-1}(x-\mbox{Tr}(A))$$ and the spectrum is $\{0,4\}$.

Comment: How did you find the eigenvalues?

Comment: @Zanzi Actually we have a result which says about any n x n rank 1 matrix  I just applied that.

Comment: @Zanzi The eigenvalues can be found by inspection. $A$’s column space is obviously one-dimensional, so that immediately gives you three of the eigenvalues, and you can always find the last eigenvalue via the trace.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Weinstein-Aronszajn determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity),

$$\begin{array}{rl} \det (s \mathrm I_n - 1_n 1_n^\top) &= \det \left( s \cdot \left( \mathrm I_n - s^{-1}1_n 1_n^\top \right) \right)\\ &= s^n \cdot \det \left( \mathrm I_n - s^{-1}1_n 1_n^\top \right)\\ &= s^n \cdot \left( 1 - n \, s^{-1} \right)\\ &= s^{n-1} \left( s-n \right)\end{array}$$

---

[linear-algebra](/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) [matrices](/questions/tagged/matrices) [determinant](/questions/tagged/determinant) [characteristic-polynomial](/questions/tagged/characteristic-polynomial)