# What is combinatorial probability a special case of?

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question

Once I complained to one of my undergrad math professors that I was hopelessly lost when it came to combinatorics and combinatorial probability problems. He remarked, half-jokingly, that combinatorics was tricky until you started solving them as a special case of *(blank)*, which to me sounded very abstract and modern.

But for the life of me I can't remember what *(blank)* was. What could it be? If it matters, I think his field was algebraic topology, but he was (still is) an old dude that just knows a heck of a lot of stuff.

For the record, I was mostly hoping to point to get an answer that would contribute to [Problems that become easier in a more general form](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/899109/117452).

Comment: Can you remember who the professor was?  And is he still alive?  If so, you might email him this question.

Comment: That's a good idea. Hopefully he checks his e-mail... after all, as of a few years ago he was still using a paper course catalog from 1999 instead of the online system.