# Factoring $x^4 + 4x^2 + 16$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was putting together some factoring exercises for my students, and came across one that I am unsure of how to factor.

I factored $x^6 - 64$ as a difference of squares, and then tried it as a difference of cubes, but was left with $(x^2 - 4)(x^4 + 4x^2 + 16)$ is there a general method for factoring $x^4 + 4x^2 + 16$?It factors into two irreducible quadratic trinomials, which is where I think the problem is stemming from.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

$$(x^2)^2+4^2+4x^2=  (x^2+4)^2-4x^2$$

Comment: ahh...the left side confuses me a bit, but you completed the square...thanks. wait a minute.

Comment: oh I see, and then you just grouped it. But what tipped you off to go in that direction?

Comment: Well regardless, I will keep it in mind in the future. Cheers.

Comment: I wouldn't call this factorization technique common, but I have seen it before a couple of times. I think that the intuition in this case just comes from experience.

Comment: agreed, that was the conclusion I came too.

Comment: how did you get -4x^2?

Comment: @Lily, $$(x^2+4)^2=?$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is another method that might generalize to more situations.

Using DeMoivre's Theorem, the roots of $x^6-64 = 0$ are $x = 2e^{ik\pi/3}$ for $k = 0,1,2,3,4,5$.

So, the polynomial is the product of the following complex linear factors:

$(x-2)(x+2)(x-2e^{i\pi/3})(x-2e^{i5\pi/3})(x-2e^{i2\pi/3})(x-2e^{i4\pi/3})$

Now pair up factors that are complex conjugates, and simplify to get:

$(x-2)(x+2)(x^2-(4\cos\frac{\pi}{3})x+4)(x^2-(4\cos\frac{2\pi}{3})x+4)$

$= (x-2)(x+2)(x^2-2x+4)(x^2+2x+4)$

Alternatively, you can first use the difference of squares factorization, and then use the sum of cubes and difference of cubes factorizations:

$x^6-64 = (x^3+8)(x^3-8) = (x+2)(x^2-2x+4)(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)$

Comment: Thanks, but the question is how to factor $x^4 + 4x^2 + 16$

Comment: Well, once you've factored $x^6-64$, then you can use $x^4+4x^2+16 = \dfrac{x^6-64}{(x-2)(x+2)}$.

Comment: Thanks again Jimmy, but you've missed the point of this question.

Comment: @drawnonward JimmyK4542 didn't miss anything. Read again what he has taken time to type up for you.

Comment: perhaps, but why would I want to consider a 6th degree polynomial to factor a 4th degree one? Thats like saying to factor 9, consider the prime factorization of 27....makes no sense.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/899109/problems-that-become-easier-in-a-more-general-form/900398#900398

Answer (score 2):

In general, if we have $x^4 + (2a - b^2)x^2 + a^2$,  we can factor it as $(x^2 + a)^2 - (bx)^2 = (x^2 - bx + a)(x^2 + bx + a)$.

On a related note, this factorization is the intuition behind the Sophie-Germain Identity:

$$x^4 + 4y^4 = (x^2 + 2y^2 + 2xy)(x^2 + 2y^2 - 2xy)$$

Indeed, plug in $a = 2y^2, b = 2y$ to get the result.

Comment: Interesting....thanks for that, I will research this identity in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^4 + 4x^2 + 16$$

Let $y = x^2$, the polynomial is then equal to

$$y^2 + 4y + 16$$

Then, use the quadratic formula:

$$y = \frac{-4 \pm \sqrt{4^2 - 4(1)(16)}}{2(1)}$$
$$y = \frac{-4 \pm \sqrt{-48}}{2}$$
$$y = 2 \pm 2i\sqrt{3}$$

Return to $x$

$$x^2 = 2 \pm 2i\sqrt{3}$$

So, we can now convert $x^4 + 4x^2 + 16$ into factors.

$$x^4 + 4x^2 + 16 = \left(x^2 - {2 + 2i\sqrt{3}}\right)\left(x^2 - {2 - 2i\sqrt{3}}\right)$$

Repeat quadratic formula for each factor.

$$x_{left} = \frac{0 \pm \sqrt{0^2 - 4(1)(2 + 2i\sqrt{3})}}{2}$$
$$x_{left} = \pm \frac{\sqrt{-8 - 8i\sqrt{3}}}{2}$$

$$x_{right} = \frac{0 \pm \sqrt{0^2 - 4(1)(2 - 2i\sqrt{3})}}{2}$$
$$x_{right} = \pm \frac{\sqrt{8i\sqrt{3} - 8}}{2}$$

So, we can now convert $x^4 + 4x^2 + 16$ into factors again.

$$x^4 + 4x^2 + 16 \\ = \left(x - \frac{\sqrt{-8 - 8i\sqrt{3}}}{2}\right)\left(x + \frac{\sqrt{-8 - 8i\sqrt{3}}}{2}\right)\\ \left(x - \frac{\sqrt{8i\sqrt{3} - 8}}{2}\right)\left(x + \frac{\sqrt{8i\sqrt{3} - 8}}{2}\right)$$

None of this is too outlandish for a student to know how to do.

**Edit:** Corrected the mistake in the quadratic formula.

**Edit:** Fixed the mistake with naively square-rooting the y-roots.

Comment: don't think so....should be b^2-4ac, but i dont think you can use the quad formula in this case.

Comment: Lets say this does work, than $(x^2 + 2 - 2i\sqrt{3})(x^2 + 2 + 2i\sqrt{3})$ should expand into our original equation, but it doesn't. Unless I'm making a mistake.

Comment: Something's still wrong. When those factors combine, it turns into $x^4 -4x^2 + 16$. I'm trying to find my logical error. Regardless, I don't think there's any restriction on using the quadratic formula.

Comment: you lost your minus b sign. yeah my galois theory is rusty, so couldn't tell you, but when I tried it this way, I wasn't getting the desired result....when you cancelled the denominator.

Comment: looks like we will be getting some fourth roots of unity or something?

Comment: @drawnonward I corrected the mistake, but when it's correct it looks really inelegant. However, if a student does give you this answer, you know that they used this method rather than the one you expect.

Comment: Haha....that's what I thought it might look like....thanks for the work anyways :) I still think you are making a sign mistake though....right at the beginning you said -4/2 = 2 should be $x^2 = -2 \pm 2i\sqrt{3}$

Comment: Yeah, although this isn't the most elegant way to do it, it's what I'd expect a student in precalculus to be able to do. Groupings like the one provided by lab bhattacharjee tend to work really well, but finding them isn't easy. Using the quadratic formula is guaranteed to work (if you use it right, unlike myself).